# Why is the newline character equal to -1?

Tags: c#, text-files

When I run this code lineLength comes back as -1, when I expect the new line character to be at the end of the string of the line of text and come back with a value corresponding as such. If the \n character is actually at the beginning of the line then how do I find the value of the last character in the line?

I tried using .length by setting lineLength equal to line.Length but when I put lineLength for the length parameter in line.substring I get an error saying:

> *"index and length must refer to a location in the string"*

```
int found;
int lineLength;
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(
        @"C:\Program Files\C# Projects\Password Validation\UserAndPWSystem2\UPInfo.txt");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("user number : "))
    {
        found = line.IndexOf(":");
        lineLength = line.IndexOf('\n');
        Console.WriteLine(lineLength);

        //Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(found + 2,lineLength));
    }
}
```

Comment: `line.IndexOf('\n')` returns -1 because `line` doesn't contain newline characters. When you can `ReadAllLines()`, it _splits_ the text of the file by newline character(s) producing an array containing the text of each line. The line-break characters themselves are not included. It has the same effect as `string.Split()`. For example: `"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',')` will only return the numbers and will _not_ include the commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs of [`ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_):

> This method opens a file, reads each line of the file, then adds each
> line as an element of a string array. It then closes the file. A line
> is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return
> ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed
> by a line feed. **The resulting string does not contain the terminating
> carriage return and/or line feed.**

`ReadAllLines` have nicely removed all the new line characters for you, and put each line as an element in the returned array. This is why `IndexOf` returns -1 - to indicate that there are no new line characters in the string.

To get the line's length, you don't need to find where the new line character is. Just use `line.Length`:

```
lineLength = line.Length;
```

> I tried using .length by setting lineLength equal to line.Length but when I put lineLength for the length parameter in line.substring I get an error saying "index and length must refer to a location in the string"?

That is because that's not how [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) works. The second parameter of the `Substring` is the *length* of the substring you want, not the end index.

In this case, if you want to substring from `found + 2` all the way to the end, you could just call the one-argument overload of `Substring`:

```
line.Substring(found + 2)
```

Comment: Thanks but I must have edited my question after you posted - I tried doing lineLength = line.Length but when I put lineLength for the length parameter in line.substring I get an error saying SystemArgumentOutOfRange: "index and length must refer to a location in the string". The issue isn't with the found variable, I tested that.

Answer (score -2):

> This method opens a file, reads each line of the file, then adds each
> line as an element of a string array. It then closes the file. A line
> is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return
> ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed
> by a line feed. The resulting string does not contain the terminating
> carriage return and/or line feed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1

The `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` function removes the carriage returns or line feeds.

Comment: Passing `lineLength - 1` will still throw an IndexOutOfRangeException (unless `found` is equal to -1). You would need `lineLength - (found + 2)` but that would be redundant because you can use the overload that doesn't require a length parameter. See Sweeper's answer above.